# Login-recuperar contraseña, Java-Swing

Tags: java-swing, java-ee

me podrían ayudar con este ejercicio de Java.
Realizar con swing, y desde un login, a través de la función de recuperar la clave del usuario,  el envío de un email con una nueva. Se adjunta el método a utilizar para enviar el mail cuando éste exista en la base de datos que se va a acceder a obtener siempre y cuando por el medio del llamada de un sp_recover_password. Definir lo necesario para su funcionamiento.

En esta linea me dice que auth no puede pasarse como parametro, estoy usando javamail 1.4.7
vi en que otras versiones de javamail si acepta el parametro auth pero no se que versiones son

> Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);

```
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class EnviarEmail {

    public static void sendEmail(String host, String port,
            final String userName, final char[] password, String toAddress,
            String subject, String message) throws AddressException,
            MessagingException {

        // sets SMTP properties
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", new Integer(port));
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", host);

        // se crea una autenticación
        Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
            public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password);
            }
        };

        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);

        // se crea un nuevo email
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(userName));
        InternetAddress[] toAddresses = { new InternetAddress(toAddress) };
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddresses);
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());
        msg.setText(message);

        // envio del email
        Transport.send(msg);

    }
```